# One activity change different fragments (different content)

Tags: android, fragment

I have 20 screens.

- 10 screens have a searchView in the top of screen and 3 tabs under this searchView
- 3 screens have a searchView in the top of screen and 2 tabs under this searchView
- 2 screens have only a searchView
- and the last 5 screens have no seachView and no tabs

So I think to do the next:

Create one global main activity that will be change fragments.

Questions:

1. Is it possible in Android? I don't want to get out of memory
2. Is it possible to write method that will return fragment with one of the next items:

   - create fragment only with N tabs
   - create fragment only with searcView
   - create fragment with N tabs and searchView
   - create fragment without tabs and without searchView

is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you won't go out of memory just because of a lot of fragments. Yes, it's possible to write a method that will return any fragment you like.

Comment: Do you have some example? Thanks.